# RuntimeError while ploting data from loop using pygtgr

Tags: python, plot, pyqtgraph, qtgui

I need to plot data generated in a loop using pyqtgraph, but every time I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type PlotDataItem has been
> deleted

This is a minimal example that generates this error. Basically, I want to create two figures and update them with new data, as the data comes in. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
import random
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self. win.resize(800, 800)
        
        # Create layout to hold multiple subplots
        pg_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    
        # Add subplots
        plot1 = pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=0, title="Sim. vs. Ml.")
        plot2 = pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=1, title="Area")
        
       
        
        self.p1 = plot1.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        self.p2 = plot2.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        
        
        
        # Show our layout holding multiple subplots
        pg_layout.show()
        
        
    def update_plot(self,data):
        self.p1.setData(data)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            x = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
            self.update_plot(x)
            

t = test()
t.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pg_layout`, `plot1` and `plot2` are local variables. As such, they will be destroyed once class initialization has been done, unless they're stored in some other living object: `plot1` and `plot2` are referenced by `pg_layout`, but, conversely, this latter (`pg_layout`) is not attached to (referenced by) any other objects.
As soon as the `__init__` function returns, `pg_layout` becomes an orphan object: `self.p1` and `self.p2` are `PlotDataItem` objects, they live in class `test` object, they are children of `pg_layout` but **they most likely do not store their parent**, and this makes `pg_layout` not attached to any living object.

By the way, `GraphicsWindow` is both deprecated and useless in this example and QApplication is a class in QtWidgets package

```
import random

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg

class test():
    def __init__(self): 
        # Create layout to hold multiple subplots
       self.pg_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    
        # Add subplots
       plot1 = self.pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=0, title="Sim. vs. Ml.")
       plot2 = self.pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=1, title="Area")
        
       
        
       self.p1 = plot1.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
       self.p2 = plot2.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        
        
        
        # Show our layout holding multiple subplots
       self.pg_layout.show()
        
        
    def update_plot(self,data):
        self.p1.setData(data)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            x = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
            self.update_plot(x)
            

t = test()
t.run()
```

To prove what inferred above, let us create  (**for didactic purpose only**) a new custom attribute for `self.p1` and `self.p2` plots to store their parent (`pg_layout`) that this time is not a class object but remains a local variable. All the rest remains the same.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self): 
        # Create layout to hold multiple subplots
       pg_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    
        # Add subplots
       plot1 = pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=0, title="Sim. vs. Ml.")
       plot2 = pg_layout.addPlot(pen=None, symbol='x', row=0, col=1, title="Area")
        
       
        
       self.p1 = plot1.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
       self.p2 = plot2.plot()                        # create an empty "plot" (a curve to plot)
        
       setattr(self.p1, 'myparent', pg_layout)
       setattr(self.p2, 'myparent', pg_layout)
        
        # Show our layout holding multiple subplots
       pg_layout.show()
```

As you can see, the code runs fine: the fact `pg_layout` has been forced to be attached to its child (and not vice versa!) `self.p1` that is a class attribute,  let it remain alive after the test object initialization.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you think you could explain that aspect of local variables better? I thought that by setting them equal to self.p1 for example I would make them class variables? This is the part that is confusing to me. Many thank!

Comment: I've edited the answer. You're right in that `plot1` and `plot2` are handled by test class object, but `pg_layout` apparently isn't. I've done my best to clearly explain what I've inferred is happening. Any other suggestion is welcome.